# Understanding the significance level of a confidence interval

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, frequentist

I generated 1000 confidence intervals with 95% significance level and I am testing H0: μ = 0 vs H1: μ != 0.

What means if 97.5% of my confidence intervals have the 0 included? It should be exactly 95% because of the significance level right?

And what means if 85% of my confidence intervals have the 0 included? It also should be exactly 95% because of the significance level.

Can someone help?

Comment: stackoverflow is for coding questions, for help on data science and statistics you should post the question on stat exchange

Answer (score 0):

It just indicates that if you repeat your experiment 100 times (e.g., draw random samples of size `n` from the population and construct the `95%` confidence interval around the test-statistic, i.e., the sample mean), then `95%` of the times the true population mean will fall inside the confidence intervals.

Since the value `0` falls inside the `95%` confidence interval constructed, `0` can be considered to be a reasonable estimate for the population mean and we fail to reject the null hypothesis H0: μ = 0.

Let's see whether the above statement makes sense through an experient;

```
# construct population
set.seed(45)
N <- 10000 # population size
X <- runif(N, min = -1, max=1)
mu <- mean(X) # population mean
# [1] 0.002494783
sigma <- sd(X) # population s.d.

set.seed(45)
mean(replicate(100, {  # repeat experiment 100 times             
            # draw samples from the population
            n <- 100 # sample size
            x <- sample(X, n)
            xbar <- mean(x) # sample mean
            se <- sigma / sqrt(n) # standard error of sample mean
            alpha <- 0.05 # significance level
            z_alpha <- qnorm(1-alpha/2)  
            # construct confidence interval around xbar
            CI <- c(xbar - z_alpha*se, xbar + z_alpha*se) 
            # test H0: mu = 0: 0 inside CI?
            (0 > CI[1]) & (0 < CI[2]) 
          }))
# [1] 0.95   # 95% of the time the CI contains 0
```

The next figure illustrates the above, the black dot correspobds to the sample mean and the horizontal bars correspond to the 95% CIs:

[image]

Comment: OKay thank you for your help. And if my $H_1$ is $\mu>0$. How do I take my conclusions? Is it the same way? If the 0 belongs to the confidence interval than  we accept the null hypothesis? In this case this is an unilateral test. I don't know if the same conditions apply because in my work I don't use a specific test. I just calculate the confidence intervals.

Comment: You reject null hypothesis H0 in favor of the alternative hypothesis H1. If your 95% CI did not contain 0 you could reject H0 in favor of H1 at 5% level of significance. In general you fail to reject H0: mu = mu_0 at certain level of significance, if your corresponding CI contains mu_0. Here your mu0 = 0.

Comment: It should be clear that rejecting the null does not mean you accept the alternative hypothesis within an NHST framework.

Comment: You *do* accept the alternative, @ShawnHemelstrand, in the sense that you claim that H1 is correct.

Comment: If you want to accept the extreme limitations that come with that conclusion sure.